# let $h:X→Y$ be continuous, with $h(x_0)=y_0$ and $h(x_1)=y_1$ . Show that $\widehat{\beta}∘(h_{x0})_∗=(h_{x1})_∗∘\widehat{\alpha}$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

**let $h:X→Y$ be continuous, with $h(x_0)=y_0$ and $h(x_1)=y_1$. Let $α$ be a path in $X$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$ , and let $β=h∘α$ . Show that $\widehat{\beta}∘(h_{x0})_∗=(h_{x1})_∗∘\widehat{\alpha}$.**

Already answer is the following:

$\widehat{\beta}∘(h_{x_0})∗([f])=[\bar{β}]⋆(h_{x_0})_∗([f])⋆[β]=[h∘\bar{α}]⋆[h∘f]⋆[h∘α]=[h∘(\bar{α}⋆f⋆α)]=( h_{x_1})∗([\bar{α}⋆f⋆α])=(h_{x_1})_∗∘\widehat{\alpha}([f]).$

But I do not understand why $[\bar{\beta}]=[h∘\bar{\alpha}]$ and why $[h∘(\bar{α}⋆f⋆α)]=( h_{x_1})∗([\bar{α}⋆f⋆α])$? Could someone help me please? Thanks

**Edit:** As someone mentioned in the comments, here are some specifications.
$\widehat{α}:π_1(X,x_0)\to π_1(X,x_1), (h_{x_0})_∗:π_1(X,x_0)→π_1(Y,y_0),
 (h_{x_1})_∗:π_1(X,x_1)\to π_1(Y,y_1), \widehat{β}:π_1(Y,y_0)\to π_1(Y,y_1)$

Comment: Could you explain your notation please? What does $\hat\beta$ mean? What is $h_{x0}$ and what is $(h_{x0})_*$? What do you mean by $f$ or $[f]$ or $[\bar\beta]$? What are $*$ and $\star$ as binary operations?

Comment: @DanRobertson I have already edited my question, take a look.

Comment: I still don’t understand your notation

Comment: @DanRobertson What do not you understand exactly?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by $[f]$ and $[\bar\beta]$ and $*$ and $\star$? So far you’ve written down the (co)domains of some of your maps. It would be nice if you wrote down what your notation means but I suppose you’re more likely to get a good answer if people have to guess what you mean first.